# Use a color gradient for a line with Mapbox

Tags: javascript, colors, gradient, mapbox, mapbox-gl

How would I change the `line-color` using Mapbox GL JS to render (from start to finish) using a color gradient instead of a single color?

```
    map.addLayer({
        'id': 'walking-line',
        'type': 'line',
        'source': 'walking',
        'layout': {
            'line-join': 'round',
            'line-cap': 'round'
        },
        'paint': {
            'line-color': '#088',
            'line-width': 5
        }
    });
```

Is this possible? I would prefer not to alter the geojson file.

Comment: can somebody answer this one to:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76227504/mapbox-gl-circle-color-with-gradient-bg-color

Answer (score 2):

```
Try this

map.addLayer({
            'id': 'walking-line',
            'type': 'line',
            'source': 'walking',
            'layout': {
                'line-join': 'round',
                'line-cap': 'round'
            },
            'paint': {
                'line-color': 'red',
                'line-width': 5,
    'line-gradient': [
                    'interpolate',
                    ['linear'],
                    ['line-progress'],
                    0, "blue",
                    0.1, "royalblue",
                    0.3, "cyan",
                    0.5, "lime",
                    0.7, "yellow",
                    1, "red"
                ]
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not (yet) supported.
See: https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-js/issues/4095

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `line-gradient` property.
See documentation: https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/style-spec/layers/#paint-line-line-gradient

A complete example of usage is available on official documentation here: https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/line-gradient/